# WPF: Border.BorderThickness=0 doesn't work

Tags: .net, wpf, layout

I have the following xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyCompany.MyApp.MySubModule.Views.MyView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="43" d:DesignWidth="115">
    <Grid>
        <Border Margin="20, 0, 0, 0" CornerRadius="0, 10, 10, 0" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop Color="#0066CC" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#0075EA" Offset="1" />
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

What I'd expect is that the `Border` would have no thickness (i.e. not be visible). But in fact you can see it. Why would that be, and how do I make it go away?

Comment: I suggest that you use snoop to see exactly where the border comes from and what values it has.

Comment: snoop is the way to go, but you can also set the BorderBrush to Green to see if its your usercontrols border :)

Answer (score 3):

The border in your code is not visible. Probably you have wrapped you usercontrol in another border or control with border.

Or maybe you think of the background? Setting the Background-property of the border fills the area covered from the border-element. To hide the whole element, set the [Visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility.aspx)-property of the border to Hidden or Collapsed or use a transparent brush as the Borders background.

BorderBrush and BorderThickness is only meant for the drawing of the border (of the control). However the Border-control is a decorator-control that has its own area (the area its child-control needs to have).

Comment: It is visible. If you paste my code into VS2010's WPF editor, you'll see that there's a gap all the way around, where I actually want the blue `Border` to extend to the very top, right and bottom of the `Grid` it's hosted in.

Comment: @Neil: What you see is the ten pixels big corner radius you have definied for your border. Its not the border that makes this, it's the background that is not drawn there. Set CornerRadius="0", if you don't want it. At the left you see the 20 pixels of the margin. Set Margin="0" if you don't like it.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be specific to the Visual Studio designer, it doesn't show up in Blend or if you actually use the control. I put a few of them in a StackPanel and there was no gap between them.

Comment: Hmm strange - I think I noticed that myself yesterday. I'll try that out now.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that I'd have used the `Visibility` attribute myself e.g.

```
<Border Visibility="Visibility.Hidden" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I just encountered the same issue and the solution (for me) is different that those posted erlier.

The fake "border" (for me) was caused by antialiasing alghoritms of layout engine. This caused some lines of the border to be "smoothed" and rendered over multiple pixels (and even if it was supposed to be invisible, there were often some artifacts left).

The solution: make sure the layout's measurements are rounded to whole pixes by setting the [UseLayoutRounding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.uselayoutrounding(v=vs.95).aspx) property of the root element to "True". (MSDN states it is set to true by default, but it seems that's not necessarily the case).

The more detailed explanation and examples: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/08/27/layout-rounding.aspx